# ¿Como generar un reporte cuyo contenido sea repetido de elementos?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2015

Buen día, estoy generando un reporte y quiero imprimir código de barras de varios productos. Suponiendo que tengo 5 productos y cada uno deseo imprimir una cierta cantidad de códigos (barras) en una hoja o lo que salga (ver adjunto)

Deseo enviar mediante parámetro las cantidades y el id de producto para poder generar el reporte.

La pregunta es **¿como programar sea por procedimiento almacenado o en código C# para indicar la cantidad a repetir de un producto?** (*ver adjunto resultado de informe*)

Tabla de cantidades a enviar
[image: Captura]

**Resultado de informe que se requiere** (DevXpress Reports o en Crystal Reports)
[image: Informe]
*Es decir repetir las cantidades ingresadas por cada tipo de producto*

Estoy usando Visual Studio 2015 (Windows Forms y C#) y un reporte de DevExpress, luego tengo un procedimiento almacenado y el reporte un dataset de enlace. Pero el resultado que me arroja solo es uno por cada registro encontrado.

---

Uso un procedimiento almacenado:

```
create procedure pa_ListarProductosInforme     
as
begin
    select codigo, marca, descripcion from tb_producto
end
```

Luego este procedimiento lo enlazo con un DataSet en Visual Studio.

Ahora para genera el informe tengo este código:

```
XtraReport xtraInforme = new XtraInforme();
private void generarInforme()
{
     documentViewer1.DocumentSource = xtraInforme;
     XtraInforme.CreateDocument();
}
```

Recuerden que esta enlazado a un DataSet y el procedimiento no requiere un parámetro.

Ahora en que momento le digo que se repita varias veces un registro?

Gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: Hola Raul.. dices en que parte del código, pero en ningún momento muestras el código que estas utilizando. ni siquiera las consultas, como para ayudarte a mejorarlas o como mejorar tu SP.

Comment: Ya corregí la pregunta, agradezco tu respuesta.

Comment: puedes basarte en esta respuesta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33327837/repeat-rows-n-times-according-to-column-value para generar un renglon por cantidad, así no tendrías que mover el dataset, solo has pruebas con cantidades grandes para ver el performace y el consumo de memoria